# MATLAB: how to darken an image? (use to make toggle button image look toggled)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a toggle buttons with custom images on them. I want them to look 'pressed' when the button is toggled.

I've tried to use 
brighter(fig, s)

but that doesn't darken the white areas of the icon.

I've also tried to do cdata = cdata+50; and then setting it back but that obviously complaines about values being too large for image. I could work around that I suppose but it there a know function that would just darken the image for me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) might be suitable here.